# Theme and plugin install or update display error in localhost

Tags: plugins, themes, updates, installation

Theme and plugin install or update display error in localhost

**"connection information error"**

in localhost how to connect the **FTP**

[image]

I'm using wordpress 4.7

Comment: Please explain your problem better.

Comment: i'm install or update the plugin in localhost display the error on the server it working

Comment: Which error? Please [edit] your question, and quote the error. Also tell us about your research efforts and what you have tried already.

Comment: it the error is **connection FTP information**

Comment: That is **not** an error, it is a prompt to request your access authentication.

Comment: in the older version of wordpress not ask to access authentication..

Comment: That doesn't make it an error. You haven't allowed the PHP user on your system to modify files, so WordPress is trying now to use the FTP user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install wordpress in the localhost

Copy the code **wp-config.php** file..

To add the this code in  **wp-config.php** file `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');`

Avoid the asking  **"connection information error"**